# Compilation error in C on Linux

Tags: c, linux, compiler-errors

I'm  writing a simple program in Linux and when compiling I keep getting this error and don't understand why — I put all `;` or `{}` in place:

`ex1.c:49.1: error:expected declaration or statement at end of input`

My code:

```
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<fcntl.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
        if (argc!=3)
                printf("Number of arugements passed is wrong - not 2\n");

        char * file1 = argv[1];
        char * file2 = argv[2];

        int fdout1 = open(file1, O_RDONLY);
        int fdout2 = open(file2, O_RDONLY);

        struct stat stat_p1,stat_p2;

        char * f1;
        char * f2;
        int i=0;

        if (fdout1 < 0 || fdout2<0)     /* means file open did not take place */
        {
                perror("ERROR opening files");   /* text explaining why */
                return 1;
        }


        if ( (stat (file1, &stat_p1) == -1) ||( stat (file2, &stat_p2) == -1) ) /* declare the 'stat' structure */
        {
                printf(" Error occurred attempting to stat files");
                return 1;
        {

        if((read(fdout1,f1,stat_p1.st_size)==-1) ||(read(fdout1,f1,stat_p1.st_size)==-1))
        {
                printf("ERROR reading files");   /* text explaining why */
                return 1;
        }
        if (stat_p1.st_size!=stat_p2.st_size)
                return 1;

        if (strcmp(f1,f2)!=0)
                return 1;

        return 0;
}
```

Can anyone tell me why I keep getting this error?

Comment: I can't count to 49 on my phone screen. Mark the offending line in the source like this: `/* <--- line 49 */`

Comment: Line 49 is the end of the code.

Comment: Well your case it's phone where is mine is slow internet. :) anyways his problem had been solved that's what matters after all.

Comment: You should use `indent`; it would have caught the mistake and reformatted your code!

Comment: the problem is a '{ where there should be a '}', at line 35.  BTW: this took approx 30 seconds to find.  I placed your code in the geany editor in a file I named ex1.c  First I noted that line 40 was the closing brace at the end of the file.  Then I scrolled backward through the file.  The inverted brace was obvious.  What linux editor are you using?

Comment: In line 35 you have an open bracket that must be a closing bracket.  Use a better editor that can check the closing brackets, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems there is a typo

```
    if ( (stat (file1, &stat_p1) == -1) ||( stat (file2, &stat_p2) == -1) ) /* declare the 'stat' structure */
    {
            printf(" Error occurred attempting to stat files");
            return 1;
    {
```

The last brace shall be a closing brace.

```
    if ( (stat (file1, &stat_p1) == -1) ||( stat (file2, &stat_p2) == -1) ) /* declare the 'stat' structure */
    {
            printf(" Error occurred attempting to stat files");
            return 1;
    }
```

Take into account that if argc is less than 3 you have to exit the program

```
if (argc!=3)
        printf("Number of arugements passed is wrong - not 2\n");
```

Otherwise these statements are invalid

```
char * file1 = argv[1];
char * file2 = argv[2];
```

Comment: Thank you!
realy helped
Ijust didnt notice it

Answer (score 3):

```
            if ( (stat (file1, &stat_p1) == -1) ||( stat (file2, &stat_p2) == -1) ) /* declare the 'stat' structure */
            {
                    printf(" Error occurred attempting to stat files");
                    return 1;
           >>>> { >>>>> change this to '}'
```

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs when you have missing closing braces. As can be seen here:

```
        if ( (stat (file1, &stat_p1) == -1) ||( stat (file2, &stat_p2) == -1) ) /* declare the 'stat' structure */
        {
                printf(" Error occurred attempting to stat files");
                return 1;
        {
```

You seem to have a typo, you should have closing brace instead of opening brace.

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this

```
if ( (stat (file1, &stat_p1) == -1) ||( stat (file2, &stat_p2) == -1) ) /* declare the 'stat' structure */
            {
                    printf(" Error occurred attempting to stat files");
                    return 1;
            }
```

The closing brace is the problem, here it was opening brace on your program.